# ¿Cómo mostrar una imagen de pre carga con Angular 2?

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Actualmente tengo un controlador donde se cargan desde un servidor externo imágenes, el problema es que aveces tardan demasiado en cargar o su carga es muy lenta por problemas de conexión del servidor que la almacena.

```
<img [src]="urlImagenLenta">
```

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de mostrar una imagen por defecto hasta que se cargue dicha imagen por completo, ya quisiera poder mostrar una animación de cargando mientras espera que se cargue la imagen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí la solución al problema usando una Imagen en memoria, extra opcion de mostrar una tercera imagen si ocurre un error al intentar cargar la imagen original:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'preload-image',
    templateUrl: '<img [src]="imgSrc">',
})
export class ImageWithPreloadComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() src: string;
    @Input() srcPreload: string;
    @Input() srcError: string;
    public imgSrc: string;
    private tmpImage: HTMLImageElement;


    constructor() {}


    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.src);
        this.imgSrc = this.srcPreload;
        if (this.tmpImage) {
            this.tmpImage.onload = null;
        }

        let loaded = () => { 
            this.imgSrc = this.src;
        };

        let imgError = () => {
            console.error('Error al cargar la imagen', this.imgSrc);
            this.imgSrc = this.srcError;
        };

        this.tmpImage = new Image();
        this.tmpImage.onload = loaded;
        this.tmpImage.onerror = imgError;
        this.tmpImage.src = this.src;
    }
}
```

Un ejemplo de como usarla:

```
<preload-image
    [src]="'https://wsurveyw.blob.core.windows.net/multimedia/profile/ef6c883c-8cd6-48d6-84f4-b4f38b8d9a76.jpg'" 
    [srcPreload]="'/assets/preload-image/progress.gif'"
    [srcError]="'https://cdn.browshot.com/static/images/not-found.png'"></preload-image>
```